# Can an 2D-array of struct type hold something like a NULL pointer?

Tags: c, struct

I want to make an array of my struct type, but it is not defined in sequence, e.g, randomly I can do `array[3] = mystruct_t;` `array[5] = mystruct_t`(`3` and `5` is defined at run-time by user input). I had tried:

it's the "ideal", but can't hold null-pointers:

```
static struct mystruct_t foo_inputs[SIZE];
```

So, I tried:

```
static struct mystruct_t *foo_inputs;
```

and then:

```
foo_inputs[x] = NULL;
```

But I get an warning:

```
 error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct mystruct_t’ from type ‘void *’
```

Ideas to implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine the two. In the first, you can't (shouldn't) assign `NULL` to a non-pointer. In the second, you have one uninitialized pointer. What you want is an array of pointers:

```
static struct mystruct_t *foo_inputs[SIZE];
foo_inputs[x] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static struct mystruct_t *foo_inputs;
```

Declares a pointer to mystruct_ts. Each element of the pointed to array must be a single struct, so trying to assign a pointer instead causes a compiler error. (You'd also get undefined behavior at runtime because you didn't allocate any memory). What you want is a double pointer (remember to allocate the memory properly!)

```
static struct mystruct_t** foo_inputs;
```

Comment: I'd stick with a normal array, as it seems the OP knows what size they want off the bat, so there's not much point in extra work dynamically allocating memory that comes with the burden of freeing it.